# Cramer's Rule yields variable in answer

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm using Cramer's Rule to derive the total effect of a change in a parameter (b) on a system of two implicit equations, $F(x,y;a,b)=0$ and $G(x,y;a)=0$ where $x,y$ are the variables and $a,b$ are parameters. However, the solutions for $\frac{dx}{db}$ and $\frac{dy}{db}$ contain $x,y$. If all I want to do is determine the sign of the effect, and I know the signs of the variables and parameters, will the sign of $\frac{dx}{db}$ and $\frac{dy}{db}$ tell me the sign of the total effect despite containing the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how "total effect" is composed of $x$ and $y$. Let's say it's $E=E(x,y)$. Then the derivative of $E$ with respect to $b$ is, by the chain rule, 
$$\frac{dE}{db}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial b} \tag{1}$$
Suppose you know the signs of all four derivatives in (1). Then you know the signs of both products in this sum. If these products turn out to be of the same sign, then $\frac{dE}{db}$ has that sign as well.  But if the products have opposite signs, you'll need to know their magnitudes to determine which one wins.